# Export text from App to Numbers/Excel

Tags: ios, iphone, excel, ios7

Is it possible to program without using a database to export text directly to a Numbers or Excel document?

I mean if you have like "name", "phonenr", "date" etc. and you want to send and save it to an excel/numbers document. Is it possible to do it by code ?
I know how to send the text as an email with code, just don't know if its possible to save it to excel/numbers document.

Tried to search for a solution to this but only thing I found was going through a db. I was thinking of avoiding it as far as I can to simplify my application. (Haven't started yet, so I don't have any example how it will look like). Hope this explanation of was enough, ask if you don't understand it :)

Comment: Create a CSV file, name it foo.xls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeahm you can do that by using excel lib for the language you are using,

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html

for ios: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/

Comment: Oh, thank you! Will look it up and I guess you solved my problem! As soon as the 8 minutes are up you get the "green check" :)